# Find all of the elements of a $\sigma$-algebra generated by a finite set of intervals

Tags: measure-theory

**The Problem:**

Let $((0,1], \mathscr{B}(0,1])$ be a measurable space, where $\mathscr{B}(0,1]$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $(0,1]$.

Find all of the elements of the sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G} = \sigma(\{(0,\frac{1}{4}], (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4}], (0, \frac{1}{2}]\})$.

**Where I Am:**

This is really annoying me. I am pretty sure that $|\mathcal{G}|$ should be $2^4 = 16$. But I can only find 14 elements:

$$\mathcal{G} \supset \{\emptyset, (0,1]\} \cup \{(0, 1/4], (1/2, 3/4], (0, 1/2]\} \cup \{(0, 1/4] \cup (1/2, 3/4], (0, 3/4]\} $$
$$ \cup \{ (1/4, 1/2], (3/4, 1], (1/2, 1], (1/4, 1/2] \cup (3/4, 1], (1/4, 1] \} $$ 
$$ \cup \{ (0, 1/4] \cup (1/2, 1], (0, 1/2] \cup (3/4, 1] \}. $$

What are two elements I'm missing? Also, is there some sort of standard "methodical" way of going about this that ensures all elements are accounted for and not double-counted? I can't seem to come up with one...

Comment: The $\sigma$-algebra can be considered to be generated by $(0,1/4]$, $(1/4,1/2]$, $(1/2,3/4]$, and $(3/4,1]$.  Do you see which elements are missing now?

Comment: Pick any subset of $\{ ({k \over 4}, {k+1 \over 4}] \}_{k=0}^3$. There are $2^4$ of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing $({1 \over 4},{3 \over 4}] $ and its complement.